# IListSource or IEnumerable error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to teach myself C# by replicating features on websites I like.

I have an ASP Repeater (Called newsRepearer) to display some news items.  It was working fine until I took out the ASP based SQL Data Source and put it in the Code Behind so that I can set a variable (Entered via a text box) to display a set number of previous days worth of news as well as implement it in a WHERE query.

When I run this code, I get the following error:

`An invalid data source is being used for newsRepeater. A valid data source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable.`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int newsDate = -7;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM igs_news WHERE DATE(newsDate) = DATEDIFF(day,@newsDays)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsDate", newsDate);

            newsRepeater.DataSource = cmd;
            newsRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

I see the error, but don't understand either the error or what IListSource and IEnumerable really are.  What am I doing wrong?

I understand the WHERE portion might be incorrect.  I will work on that once this is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind your repeater against an object which implements the IListSource or IEnumerable interface, the SqlCommand class does not meet that qualification; however a DataSet does. So try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int newsDate = -7;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM igs_news WHERE DATE(newsDate) = DATEDIFF(day,@newsDays)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsDate", newsDate);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();

            newsRepeater.DataSource = ds;
            newsRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it, thanks.  I will have to spend some time researching that.

Comment: No problem, please mark the answer as accepted if it meets your needs.

There are multiple ways to retrieve your data from a SQL query, such as DataSet, DataReader, DataTable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

And just for anyones future reference, I was close but not quite there with the WHERE query to select the last 7 days worth of news items from the Database.  The below did what I wanted.

`SELECT * FROM igs_news WHERE newsDate < DATEDIFF(day,@newsDate,GETDATE())`